# All links in my site start with localhost?

Tags: windows, iis

This is my website `http://173.214.165.83/`. The home page shows, but all links start with localhost/wordpress, rather than the current address, which is 173.214.165.83.

The server is windows and runs IIS 7. Wordpress is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress. Wordpress is installed by [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

I'm new to IIS. How should I fix the link problem?

I hope I don't have to reinstall wordpress.

Comment: What I noticed is, you have set site url as http://gqqnbig.me but your website is in http://gqqnbig.me/wordpress Use following queries to change site urls in WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure the URL that WP uses for the links in the backend, at Settings->General.

Comment: Okay but in 2022/WP 5.9.1 is that WordPress Address (URL) or Site Address (URL)? Which config item gets popluated to all auto-generated links?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because you did not change all domain URL values stored in database, mostly on posts.

There are two solutions. (second one is recommended)

1. Either define these variables in wp-config.php. These will override any domain URL values stored in database.

   ```
   define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://173.214.165.83' );
   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://173.214.165.83' );
   ```

This will work fine but if you ever delete these lines from wp-config.php, your wordpress will start using URL from database. So `http://localhost/wordpress` will be displayed

1. Run SQL query to modify URLs permanently. From phpmyadmin or any other solution.

   ```
   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsite.com', 'http://173.214.165.83') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldsite.com','http://173.214.165.83');
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldsite.com', 'http://173.214.165.83');
   ```

Don't forgot to replace `http://www.oldsite.com` with your old urls in above SQL queries.
I think you have `http://localhost/wordpress`

Comment: If I have two domain names, if I visit it by www.name1.com, wordpress's links start with name1, if I visit it by www.name2.com, the links start with name2. I think it is what relative url does. Doesn't wordpress support?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"https://"` before the link and add `target = "_blank"`

JavaScript:

```
var url = "gmail.com";

if(!url.match(/http/g)) {
    var addHead = "https://";
    var url = addHead + fileName;
} else {
    var url = fileName;
}
```